# ASCII characters causing issue with onclick() javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, razor

I am trying to create an `onclick` element that plays a song when the play button is clicked. The way I have it set up works great for songs that do not contain an apostrophe, but for those that do, the song does not play.

Here's the site so you can test: https://www.unearthapp.io/Home/New (hover over a song to click the play button)

The song that doesn't work is "Don't Say You Love" here's the corresponding code in the html:

Here's the html

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Album", new { ID = item.Album.AlbumID })">@item.Title</a><span class="feat-artists">@item.Artist</span>
```

And the corresponding javascript

```
function playPauseClick(_songID, title, artist, url, imageURL)
{
    songID = _songID;
    var song =
    {
        songID: songID,
        title: ((title != null && title != "" && title != "null") ? title : ''),
        artist: ((artist != null && artist != "" && artist != "null") ? artist : ''),
        file: url,
        imageURL: (imageURL != "" ? imageURL : SITEROOT_ABSOLUTE + "/resources/images/album_ph.jpg"),
        howl: null
    }
    if(player == null)
    {
        player = new Player([ song ]);
    }
    else
    {
        player.playlist.push(song);
    }
    playPauseBtn = $("#playPauseBtn" + songID);
    resetPlayPauseBtns();
    if(playPauseBtn.hasClass("ion-ios-play") && !playPauseBtn.hasClass("resumesong"))
    {
        player.skipTo(player.playlist.length - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        togglePlayPauseBtn();
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: there's 14 different ASCII characters in "Don't Say You Love" - which one is the problem?

Comment: The title reaching the `playPauseClick` function is the string `'Don&#39;t Say You Love'` (as shown in generated page source). Where the apostrophe is replaced by the character entity is unknown to me, but taking it into account would  seem to be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

What about this

```
var str = "Don't Say You Love";
var res = str.replace("'", "\'");
```

Comment: It should be stated that when a user submits a new song that the variable for the song title and any other user submitted data should be sanitized before being stored. Your solution is correct, it just doesn't explain where the code should go and why. 

The poster provided the code to play the song, but he needs to modify the code that handles when the user submits a new song. This can either be done in javascript before it gets sent to the server or on the server before it gets saved to his database.

Answer (score -1):

Found your error.

```
(function(event){playPauseClick('82', 'Don't Say You Love', 'SITA', 'https://ucarecdn.com/20bd363d-b830-4676-87f0-7734db3752e4/', 'https://ucarecdn.com/c27c2c47-1c5e-46fa-ab13-feb5d4a7c6a6/');
})
```

This issue is this

```
'Don't Say You Love'
```

either use `Don\'t` or `"Don't Say You Love"`
The problem here is your single quotes in Don't

Comment: Is there a way to automatically add the slash? I do not control the naming of the song as it is submitted by a user